# Changing image source attribute on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, image

I have a requirement where I want to change source of image on mouse hover. The way I am doing this is:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('img').addEventListener('mouseover', function() 
{
    document.getElementsByTagName('img').setAttribute('src', 'url/of/the/image');
});
```

I want to know is this correct way of doing this. Or should add an overlay div on image tag and show my image there?

Comment: Two things to note here - first, you are changing **ALL** `<img>` tags with this code - I think you'd only want to change a specific image... Secondly, you might want to think about pre-loading the final image so that there is no load time after the user triggers the hover event.

Comment: Yes, I want to attach mouse over event to all images.
Secondly, Yes I playing with opacity of image one user mouse over. I just want to know is it correct way of doing it?

Answer (score -1):

With jQuery you can do it like this:

```
$('img').on('mouseover', function(e) {
   $(this).attr('src', '/link/to/image').css({}); // change src and css
   // or you can use div with background image style property
})
```

Comment: It is clear that you are just trying to help but suggesting jquery for this is a bit over-kill.